# Running tensorflow on server Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

trying to use tensorflow on ipage server with operating system centOs 7

I don't know if there is a GPU or not , but I get this error message

**kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist**

I tried this code

```
from tensorflow import config
config.set_soft_device_placement = True
```

and also this code trying to prevent tensorflow from using GPU

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
```

but I kept receiving the same error message

**Note :**
I am trying to run face recognition script on server to be used by php through terminal  using exec() function by passing the image as string base64 and then decoding it and then adding new face or fetching faces and comparing and then will be saved in the database

and this is my script :

```
import face_recognition as fr
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import base64
import io
import json
import cv2 

from tensorflow import config
config.set_soft_device_placement = True

def check_if_spoof(image_string_base64):
    # decoding the image 
    msg = base64.b64decode(image_string_base64)
    buf = io.BytesIO(msg)
    img = Image.open(buf).convert("RGB")
    opencv_image = np.array(img)
    test_image = opencv_image[:,:,::-1].copy()

    json_file = open('antispoofing_models/antispoofing_model.json','r')
    loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
    json_file.close()
    model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
    # load antispoofing model weights 
    model.load_weights('antispoofing_models/antispoofing_model.h5')
    resized_face = cv2.resize(test_image,(160,160))
    resized_face = resized_face.astype("float") / 255.0
    # resized_face = img_to_array(resized_face)
    resized_face = np.expand_dims(resized_face, axis=0)
    # pass the face ROI through the trained liveness detector
    # model to determine if the face is "real" or "fake"
    preds = model(resized_face)[0]
    if preds> 0.5:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def decode_img(image_string_base64):
    msg = base64.b64decode(image_string_base64)
    buf = io.BytesIO(msg)
    img = Image.open(buf)
    return img

def resize_image(image_string_base64, height=500):
    image = decode_img(image_string_base64)
    height_percent = (height / float(image.size[1]))
    width_size = int((float(image.size[0]) * float(height_percent)))
    image = image.resize((width_size, height), Image.NEAREST)
    return np.array(image)

def add_person(image_string_base64):
    if check_if_spoof(image_string_base64):
        return {'error':'image is fake'}

    img = np.array(decode_img(image_string_base64))
    img_encodings = fr.face_encodings(img, num_jitters=4)
    return np.array(img_encodings)

def get_person(image_string_base64, data, tolerance=0.35):
    if check_if_spoof(image_string_base64):
        return {'error':'image is fake'}

    data = json.loads(data)
    resized_img = resize_image(image_string_base64)
    img_encoding = fr.face_encodings(resized_img)

    ############## testing purpose only #########
    # return fr.compare_faces(data,img_encoding)
    #############################################

    # type of recieved data is : { id ->number : encoding->list}
    for user in data:
        for id_ , encoding in user:
            if True in fr.compare_faces(encoding, img_encoding):
                return id_
    return {'error':"user not existed"}
```

Comment: What error message?

Comment: This " kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist"

Comment: Read the line that comes after that message, where it says to ignore if you do not have a Nvidia GPU.

Comment: The program stops after that message , there is no another line

Comment: There should be, maybe its being hidden by other means in your code, as this code is not really runnable (its incomplete).

Comment: I think i forgot to print the result function , the function only returns doesn't print , so i think there is no error .
maybe everything was running correctly